# Android remove all recyclerview with animation on a button click

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a recycler view. On a button click I want to remove all the items from the recyclerview but the items must be removed with animation. 
I am able to remove all the items at once but I don't know how to remove them with animation. Thanks

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators or this one https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators

Answer (score 3):

It's old, but wish this helps someone else as it's already not answered yet; I have done it by deleting a single item at a time by simulating a swipe animation on this item, and post a delay before deleting the next item, and so on to the way down to the last item of the `RecyclerView`

**Step No.1:**

In your activity that holds the clear all button and the `RecyclerView` instance: Create a method of single item delete

```
private void deleteItem(View rowView, final int position) {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(),
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    anim.setDuration(300);
    rowView.startAnimation(anim);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (myDataSource.size() == 0) {
                addEmptyView(); // adding empty view instead of the RecyclerView
                return;
            }
            myDataSource.remove(position); //Remove the current content from the array
            myRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Refresh list
        }

    }, anim.getDuration());
}
```

**Step No.2:**

Create the method that will delete all `RecyclerView` list items >> call it in your button click callback.

```
boolean mStopHandler = false;

private void deleteAllItems() {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (myDataSource.size() == 0) {
                mStopHandler = true;
            }

            if (!mStopHandler) {
                View v = myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView;
                deleteItem(v, 0);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, 250);
        }
    };
    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
}
```

Also it's important to handle configuration change in manifest, activity section, as if the configuration changes while clearing your recycler view list, an exception will be raised

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
</activity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) is a pretty good library and what's better is the documentation for it. You can even insert durations for transitions and animations.

Also, remember that if you are using default animation, after calling `myDataSet.remove(pos)` using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` while there is an animation ongoing will cause the animation to stop.

Comment: I want to remove all my elements at once. 
I dont know how to achieve that.

Comment: They will go in a certain order according to how you go through your loop, so try the counter: Execute both `myDataSet.remove(pos)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` sequentially fro every item. Or you can try the same library that I mentioned with command `recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setRemoveDuration(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Extend BaseItemAnimator class of [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) library:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(null);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new MyScaleInLeftAnimator());

findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int count = adapter.getItemCount();
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, count);
        }
    }
);
```

...

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ArrayList<String> mItems;

    ...

    public void clear() {
        if (mItems != null) {
            mItems.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

...

```
public class MyScaleInLeftAnimator extends BaseItemAnimator {

    private long lastRemoval;
    private int removeCount;

    public MyScaleInLeftAnimator() {
        lastRemoval = 0;
        removeCount = 0;
    }

    public MyScaleInLeftAnimator(Interpolator interpolator) {
        mInterpolator = interpolator;
        lastRemoval = 0;
        removeCount = 0;
    }

    @Override protected void preAnimateRemoveImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        ViewCompat.setPivotX(holder.itemView, 0);
    }

    @Override protected void animateRemoveImpl(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long d = time - lastRemoval;
        if (d < 100) {
            removeCount++;
        } else {
            removeCount = 0;
        }
        lastRemoval = time;
        ViewCompat.animate(holder.itemView)
                .scaleX(0)
                .scaleY(0)
                .setDuration(getRemoveDuration())
                .setInterpolator(mInterpolator)
                .setListener(new DefaultRemoveVpaListener(holder))
                .setStartDelay(removeCount * 100)
                .start();
    }

    @Override protected void preAnimateAddImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        ViewCompat.setPivotX(holder.itemView, 0);
        ViewCompat.setScaleX(holder.itemView, 0);
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(holder.itemView, 0);
    }

    @Override protected void animateAddImpl(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        ViewCompat.animate(holder.itemView)
                .scaleX(1)
                .scaleY(1)
                .setDuration(getAddDuration())
                .setInterpolator(mInterpolator)
                .setListener(new DefaultAddVpaListener(holder))
                .setStartDelay(getAddDelay(holder))
                .start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, the views are disappearing with fading animation. Can I please have the slide out animation in same code

Comment: you can extend SimpleItemAnimator class and Implement the animation that you need. Example here: [link](http://blog.trsquarelab.com/2015/12/creating-custom-animation-in.html)

Comment: Also you can use the @MRX advice and use the [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) library. It's easy to use: add compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6' to your app build.gradle and call recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());

Comment: I already tried that library & also called the rView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator()); but the problem is, all my elements are sliding to left at once only, what I want is one item at a time will get animated towards the left. Like one view slides to left, then second and gradually last visible item slides out left

Comment: Extend BaseItemAnimator class of [recyclerview-animators](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) library (see MyScaleInLeftAnimator class above).

Comment: Hi again, I did everything that I could. Even tried extending BaseItemAnimator class, but I exactly don't know how to use it. 
In the example above, it does not provide any implementation of animation while removing all data from the list.

Comment: While deleting ViewHolder the MyScaleInLeftAnimator class checks the lastRemoval time and if necessary adds 100 milliseconds to the start time of ViewHolder removal animation. Therefore, when we removing all data, animation for deleting each ViewHolder starts with a delay of 100 milliseconds relative to the previous deleted ViewHolder.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have done without using any libraries - by inserting delays in the loop to remove items & restore (if needed)

```
clearItemsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final List<LineItem> lineItemsCopy = new ArrayList<>(lineItems);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.removeItem(0);
                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, getString(R.string.items_cleared_message), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(getString(R.string.label_undo), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    for (int i=0; i<lineItemsCopy.size(); i++) {
                                        final int finalI = i;
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                salesOrderItemListAdapter.restoreItem(lineItemsCopy.get(finalI), 0);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(500);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                    }).setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
```