# How to remove all Items from RecyclerView with nice animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have to achieve list view with expanding and collapsing  animation in list view. I have an method using do this but it did not work on `RecyclerView` view. Whole `RecyclerView` going to be visible for short time and animation start after that.  [Refer the GIF in this link](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953852/why-image-rotation-animation-only-works-correctly-for-the-first-time?rq=1).

As an alternative I follow this [post](https://proandroiddev.com/enter-animation-using-recyclerview-and-layoutanimation-part-1-list-75a874a5d213) and by adding and removing all items (it's always going to have less than 5 items so no performance issue) with using
`LayoutAnimation` achieved following.

[image]

As you can see list view item reveal animation working. To hide the item reverse the properties in animation file like below and apply it after removing all the data from `RecyclerView`

**item_remove_animation_drop_down.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="@integer/anim_duration_medium">

        <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-20%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

        <alpha
            android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
            />

        <scale
            android:fromXScale="100%"
            android:fromYScale="100%"
            android:toXScale="95%"
            android:toYScale="95%"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" />

    </set>
```

**layout_animation_fall_down.xml**

```
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/item_add_animation_fall_down"
    android:delay="15%"
    android:animationOrder="normal" />
```

**Method in adapter**

```
public void runItemRemoveAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_drop_down);

        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    }
```

**Code in Fragment**

```
private void onClickSelectPromotionContainer() {
        selectPromotionContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (discountListExpanded) {

                    promoListData.removeAll(promosDataFromServer);
                    discountListAdapter.runItemRemoveAnimation(discountRecyclerView);
                    selectPromotionImage.startAnimation(rotatePlus180);
                    discountListExpanded = false;

                } else {

                    discountRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    promoListData.addAll(promosDataFromServer);
                    discountListAdapter.runItemAddAnimation(discountRecyclerView);
                    selectPromotionImage.startAnimation(rotateMinus180);
                    discountListExpanded = true;

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But it did not create any animation. I think because it's remove all the data I think. So is there a way to add nice animation when clearing list view that can be use to convince user that list is hiding ? Or am I doing something wrong in my code ? It should be the reverse of the item adding animation to keep it nice and should be vertical animation.

Comment: oh I need the same :S no luck from my side

Comment: I think it is because you are removing them. Did you try running the animation without removing, then removing after the animation is finished?

Comment: You can have a look on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779292/android-remove-all-recyclerview-with-animation-on-a-button-click/54357801#54357801